# Xen Networking - Separating Dom0 from DomU

Tags: xen, bridge

I'm having some issues regarding Xen Networking and I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction.

I have a server with 2 NICS (Xen over Ubuntu Server - Xen Bridge scripts)
Each NIC has an IP in totally seperate networks:
NIC 1- External IP 
NIC 2- Internal IP 
I would like to set up NIC1 to connect directly to a DOMU VM and NIC2 to connect only to the Dom0 management console.

How should I set this up?

Cheers for the help.

Sorry for the lack of info.
The idea is the following:
I want to set up a virtual router as a Xen DomU (Debian + IPtables)
This virtual router will have 3 vifs:
-vif1.0 = external IP
-vif1.1 = vlan1 (xapi1)
-vif1.2 = vlan2 (xapi2)
For Xen Dom0 I have one internal IP. I want it so that the Dom0 IP and the DomU IP cannot communicate in any way(these two networks have no route between them).
I asked my university for both IPs and they gave me one for external and one for internal. Both IPs are limited to the MAC address of my server's NICS.
I have played around with Xen Bridges and what I get is xenbr1 with an IP for dom0 and all the other VM's have a vif on this same bridge giving them an IP in the same network. Thus making communication possible between my VMs and dom0.

Comment: Do you want to connect from the Dom0 to the DomUs via NIC1 or is the console-access enough?

Comment: I would like Dom0 to be totally separate from DomU's in terms of networking. 
Only way to access DomU being vnc ssh tunnel via NIC2/Openxencenter NIC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite some information missing to give you a precise answer, because possible setups depend on your demands and network constrains (is your external port limited to the MAC-Address of the external NIC? Is there some fancy tagged/untagged VLAN-Setup for internal/external traffic?...). As such my answer might be a little bit generic.

For the internal NIC, you just configure your eth-device for NIC 2 as any other server you have within your internal network. Since your server seems to be within the public and private network, be sure to take security precautions! (read: at least appropriate firewall rules)

For your external NIC you can simply create a bridge device for your VM and configure the external interface directly in the VM. This only works if your external switch/router-port isn't limited to the MAC-Address of your external NIC. Otherwise you have to configure the external NIC on your Dom0 and route the traffic from/to the VM, or request to allow the VM-MAC-Address.

However, if you need resources how to setup this, there should be plenty of tutorials using the keywords: *xen routed bridged networking*

Comment: Info added to the initial question. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

NIC2 Should not be bridged at all. Configure here an IP for your Dom0.

NIC1 should not have an IP on the Dom0 - just provide a bridge with that interface.
Use that bridge to connect the DomUs to.

Comment: As in eth0 directly has an IP and eth1 bridged to xenbr1?

Comment: @user2284355 Yes - but this is probably xenbr0 - you do not need two bridges.